fbgemm.dll module could not be found when using Pytorch/transformers
I currently am trying to use the BERT language model for invoice creation. However, i am receiving the error:
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.
I have tried installing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable to fix this issue, but issue was not fixed. I am pretty stuck here after this.

solved by downloading libomp140.x86_64.dll and adding it to folder with fbgemm.dll

This solution works, “solved by downloading libomp140.x86_64.dll and adding it to folder with fbgemm.dll”, and the file end with .dll can be download from here, https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/libomp140_x86_64/00637fe34a6043031c9ae4c6cf0a891d
